# Serialization in Geth Android

Tags: go-ethereum, android

```
KeyStore keyStore = new KeyStore(seedFile.toString(), Geth.LightScryptN, Geth.LightScryptP);
byte[] jsonAccount = keyStore.exportKey(keyStore.getAccounts().get(0), seed, seed);
Account importAccount = keyStore.importKey(jsonAccount, seed, seed);

transaction = Geth.newTransaction(nonceValue, Geth.newAddressFromHex(toAddress), new BigInt(amount), gas, new BigInt(gasTransaction), null);
transaction = keyStore.signTxPassphrase(importAccount, seed, transaction, new BigInt(3));
```

By using this code I signed transaction successfully and got all the value successfully.

Then I'm calling API by passing hash value to send transaction.

```
transaction.getSigHash().getHex()
```

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_sendRawTransaction&hex=yourhex&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

I'm getting response like this.

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid RLP.","data":"RlpIncorrectListLen"},"id":1}
```

Please help me who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Geth transaction object has a method encodeRLP() - the result of this method is what you need to send to etherscan - not the signature hash

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I got byte array from encodeRLP(). And convert byte array to base64 string.
But the string is not generated properly.

Comment: you need to convert to hex - not base64 - you can e.g. khex for this https://github.com/walleth/khex - and then just use ByteArray.toHexString()

Comment: Thank you so much ligi.
By your help my transaction is working perfectly.

Comment: You are very welcome - please accept the answer when it solves your problem.

Comment: My wallet runs completely. But as geth.aar works on file so if I want to generate same address in different device then is it possible?

Comment: Please ask as a separate question - and try to be a bit more verbose - I do not really understand your current problem

Comment: Please check this.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57234/generate-same-address