# Generate same address

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I used Geth.aar library for ethereum and it's running completely on same device.

But when I changed device and restore wallet from seed at that time new address is generated instead of previous address.

Because Geth.aar runs on file and in different device it creates new file and according to that file it creates new address.

Is there any way in Geth.aar to generate same address every time on any device?